# Can i split a column on my data table into multiple columns based on a character search

Tags: c#, datatable

Hi all I'm trying to do is write a code on C# to split a particular column in my data table into 2 columns as shown below

Just as an example

```
Name   Location
-----  --------
ross    a12u20
charle  b12u25
```

and I want this to be like

```
Name   Location   Unit
-----  --------   -----
ross    a12        u20
charle  b12        u25
```

Is this possible?

Comment: _Is this possible?_ Did you try it?

Comment: I tried.. I was able to split a row into multiple row... But the same concept is now holding good and im sure it shouldnt as well... I am trying to understand if it is possible.. and if it is would you suggest me how i can do it... I am really not an expert at c# and in my learning stages.. would be great if you could tell me the approach i can take to get this done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some information missing.

Assuming the Location property is always 6 chars long, or the unit starts at index 4 this could  be a quick and dirty solution:

```
List<person> source = new List<person>();
//I have created a ficitive class person with 2 properties: Name, Location
source.Add(new person { Name ="Ross", Location="a12u15"});
source.Add(new person { Name ="bald", Location="b12u20"});
source.Add(new person { Name ="fat", Location="c12u25"});
source.Add(new person { Name ="man", Location="d12u30"});
source.Add(new person { Name ="heinz", Location="e12u35"});


var result = source.Select(s => new {
    Name = s.Name,
    Location = s.Location.Substring(0,3),
    Unit = s.Location.Substring(3,3)
});
```

Edit: To read from a datatable the query would look different. `source` would be your datatable.

```
var result = source.Select(s => new {
    Name = s.Field<string>("Name"),
    Location = s.Field<string>("Location").Substring(0,3),
    Unit = s.Field<string>("Location").Substring(3,3)
});
```